# how to hide a column from google.visualization.table w/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

google does not make any styles than you can hide etc. perhaps jquery can be used?

```
var table =
            new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.setColumns([2]); <-- this does not work
        table.draw(response.getDataTable(), {showRowNumber: false});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the google api documents shows no method for setColumns on a datatable object. though you can use

```
table.removeColumn([2]);
```

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#DataTable_removeColumns

Comment: I receive   Message: Object doesn't support this property or method        (the method is for DataTable only?)

Comment: you are right I mistoke your statement from using table vs. datatable. 

after checking the API for visualization, your option might be to use a patternformatter http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#patternformatter

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite late reply, but hope some one else finds it helpful.

You can use DataView instead of DataTable to bind your charts.

The syntax I use is as below:

```
table.draw(response.getDataTable(), {
    showRowNumber: false,
    'view': { 'columns': [0, 1, 4,5] }
});
```

This will add only those columns to the data view that you have mentioned.

In the eventlistener you can still have .getDataTable() to fetch the entire record.

Regards
Avni

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem finding a way to hide one(two in my case) column alone.

What I am doing: I am visualizing the data in google map, and using the same data to create the table visualization also. Both table and map are linked together by listeners. Example: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#Example

Problem: Though the data I am using to visualize map and table are the same, I don't want the table to show latitude and longitude.

I am still living with the table that shows lat and long.